# Python dispatcher and scenario-specific functions and sub-functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write several functions in Python (dispatcher +  scenario-specific functions and sub-functions) as follows:

```
def dispatcher(event):
    if event['name'] == 'func_a':
        return func_a(event['data'])
    # several elif statements here
    elif event['name'] == 'func_n':
        return func_n(event['data'])


def func_a(data):
    """ multi-scenario function returning dict"""
    # Scenario A
    if data['certain_param'] == 'certain value':
        # do something
        # that takes several lines of code
        return {'result': 'scenario A'}

    # Scenario B
    elif data['certain_param'] == 'another value':
        # do something else
        # that takes several lines of code
        return {'result': 'scenario B'}

    # some other elif scenarios go here

    return {'result': 'Fail'}


# func_b(), func_c(), .... go here (similar to func_a())


def func_n(data):
    """ similar logic to funcs a, b, ...."""
    pass
```

I want to break a very long **func_a()** into several sub-functions (one for each scenario). Here are 2 options:

```
# makes 2 calls to each scenario sub-function (not ideal)
def func_a(data):
    """ same func_a() above"""
    # Scenario A
    if func_a_scenario_a(data):
        return func_a_scenario_a(data)

    # other elifs

    # Scenario N
    elif func_a_scenario_n(data):
        return func_a_scenario_n(data)
```

Yet another way to write **func_a()** is:

```
# Not very Pythonic
def func_a(data):

    result = func_a_scenario_a(data)
    if result:
        return result

    result = func_a_scenario_b(data)
    if result:
        return result

    # repeat for every scenario
```

What is (are) better ways to do the above? maybe using eval('some_func()')? or something else? Thanks.

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store key value pairs; here, the values are the functions to be called and the key tells the dispatcher which value to unlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a decorator which can then determine what to pass to its wrapped function. The decorator can store a dictionary with the function name as the key, and an associated value to be passed to the function with the same name as the key:

```
def dispatcher(f):
   registry = {'func_a':"arbitrary_data", 'func_n':"arbitrary_data_1"}
   def wrapper(data):
      return f(registry[f.__name__])
   return wrapper

@dispatcher
def func_a(data):
  #do something with data
  return 

@dispatcher
def func_n(data):
  #do something with data
  return 

func_a("somedata")
func_n("someotherdata") #functions called be called normally
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked with some modifications: the registry was a mapping of context_data to functions (not strings). e.g. registry = {'context_value_1': func1, 'context_value_2': func2}